# Transferring contents of 1 column of sql table to another

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables :

wp_groups(ID,groupname, groupdesc, read_access,write_access, ip_range);
wp_usermeta(umeta_id,user_id,meta_key,meta_value);

I wish to transfer the following contents of wp_usermeta to groupname column of wp_groups:

```
SELECT DISTINCT meta_value
FROM  `wp_usermeta` 
WHERE meta_key =  'rpr_new_name'
```

read_access and write_access have to be set to "group" and the others set to ''.
ID will probably autoincrement as is set.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I tried the following sql query : "INSERT INTO wp_groups (groupname) VALUES  (SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM  `wp_usermeta` WHERE meta_key =  'rpr_new_name');

It gave an error.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'rpr_new_name')' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the subquery you have wrote !! as you column i think is a varchar you must place the subquery inside a " " - so the code shoul be :

```
 INSERT INTO wp_groups(groupname) VALUES 
("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'rpr_new_name'");
```

Hope i could help ! and yes error treatment in mysql is not that good !! kkk

Comment: You mean like 

    INSERT INTO 'wp_groups' groupname,groupdesc,read_access,write_access,ip_range) VALUES (SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM  `wp_usermeta`,"","group","group", "") WHERE meta_key =  'rpr_new_name';

Comment: yes something like that !! you adjust the content and col names !